# Aron Granbergs Unity Pathfinding AI goes back and forth

Tags: path-finding, unity

The agent goes back and forth after calculating the path with `seeker.StartPath (transform.position,target.transform.position, OnPathComplete);`. The gizmo shows the correct path. Please watch this short video to get an impression on what happens. 
It starts after adding about 100 obstacles during runtime. Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong? My test case is really simple. I can provide the project if necessary.

Link to the Video:
http://screencast.com/t/2ww04975l